# Is there any way to pass html content while triggering mailto: option?

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, html, hyperlink

While triggering `mailto:` link, is there any way to pass some predefined HTML to the opening mail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to pass the HTML in email body while using `mailto` link. It takes only string/text value.

Check this official documentation for more information: [Creating hyperlinks](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Introduction_to_HTML/Creating_hyperlinks)

Also, check this thread for more explanation: [mailto link with HTML body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5620324/mailto-link-with-html-body)

It says, *for line breaks, instead of using `<br />` use `%0D%0A`*.