# JSON formatting: make some words inside body text of email bold

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, json

I know how to make text bold in its entirety, but is there a way to make SOME text within my email body bold?

Example:

```
"&body=This is a test"
```

How do I only make the word 'test' bold using JSON formatting?

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32947586/mailto-and-format-bold-italic. Let me know if it answers your question.

Comment: Hi Ganesh, if I read this correctly, I shouldn't implement this for it is some sort of misuse of URI encoding. If this is the case I will refrain from it.

Comment: Yes, correct. Not supported officially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not officially supported to format email body to bold the text as you are using `mailto`. Also, it does not support using HTML in email body.

Check related threads here:

1. [Is there any way to pass html content while triggering mailto: option?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/294905/is-there-any-way-to-pass-html-content-while-triggering-mailto-option/294907#294907)
2. [How do I pass HTML table inside mailto in anchor tag?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/305434/how-do-i-pass-html-table-inside-mailto-in-anchor-tag/305437#305437)

---

There is a workaround by using special characters in JavaScript as mentioned in below thread. However, it should not be used for security concerns as mentioned in the thread. Also, you may not be able to convert the JavaScript code mentioned in thread to SharePoint JSON formatting.

[Mailto and format (bold, italic, ...)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32947586/mailto-and-format-bold-italic)