# SharePoint JSON hyperlink text in email

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, column-formatting

I have a list that has a combination of numbers. In one of the columns for that list I am writing JSON code that pops up outlook with a set template.

In the body of that template, I have the following:

"Column: ", "http://test.com/", "[$column]", and so on.

The end result is: `http://test.com/column`

This is the result I want but I want the text to be different. For example, the column value would be displayed and then the link above would be hyperlinked.

Is there anyway to accomplish this using JSON?

Comment: Can you add the JSON you are using currently to your question?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you will be able to set the hyperlink with display/description text and link using SharePoint JSON formatting `mailto` functionality as it is not possible to pass the HTML in email body while using mailto link. It takes only string/text value.

Check this official documentation for more information: [Creating hyperlinks](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Introduction_to_HTML/Creating_hyperlinks)

You can find more information about this in below threads:

1. [Is there any way to pass html content while triggering mailto: option?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/294905/is-there-any-way-to-pass-html-content-while-triggering-mailto-option/294907#294907)
2. [How do I pass HTML table inside mailto in anchor tag?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/305434/how-do-i-pass-html-table-inside-mailto-in-anchor-tag/305437#305437)
3. [JSON formatting: make some words inside body text of email bold](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/307246/json-formatting-make-some-words-inside-body-text-of-email-bold/307258#307258)