# SharePoint JSON email attachment

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, column-formatting

Is there anyway to add an attachment to Outlook using `mailto:` in JSON?

For example, I have a list that has an attachment. I have a email template that opens in one of the columns using JSON. I am trying to attach the document in the list to the email.

Is this possible with JSON?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, No.

You cannot add an attachment to outlook email using `mailto` in SharePoint JSON formatting.

`mailto` protocol only accepts string/text values as input. So, you cannot pass attachments or HTML content using the `mailto` protocol.

Check this official documentation for more information: [Creating hyperlinks](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Introduction_to_HTML/Creating_hyperlinks)

You can find more information about this in below threads:

1. [Is there any way to pass html content while triggering mailto: option?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/294905/is-there-any-way-to-pass-html-content-while-triggering-mailto-option/294907#294907)
2. [How do I pass HTML table inside mailto in anchor tag?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/305434/how-do-i-pass-html-table-inside-mailto-in-anchor-tag/305437#305437)
3. [JSON formatting: make some words inside body text of email bold](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/307246/json-formatting-make-some-words-inside-body-text-of-email-bold/307258#307258)